# How do I overwrite files in my local directory with files from GitHub without erasing changes?

Tags: git, github, command-line

The requirements for the task I want to do is as follows:

- Overwrite files in local directory with master files
- **However**, any files that do not exist in the master branch should not be erased

i.e. I have files **a**, **b**, and **c** in my master branch.

I have files **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d** in my local directory.

Files **b** and **c** are out of date in my local directory, so I want to overwrite them with **b** and **c** from the master branch.

However, while doing so, I do not wish for file **d** to be erased.

*(Note: I do not wish to just update b and c manually because, in my case, I am working with many files. So, I don't want to pull all of those files manually.)*

Also, to be more clear, I wish to do this from the command line. (I'm using the terminal on my Mac if that helps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to stash changes and then unstash once you've pulled.

In short it's pretty much:

```
git stash  
git pull
git stash apply
```

Further information about stashing can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

The above is for if the files you don't want to erase haven't been committed yet. For files that have been committed but not pushed to `origin` then `git pull --rebase` might be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Pull master and accept `--theirs` if conflict occurs.

```
$ git pull origin master -s recursive -X theirs
```

---

**Alternative:**

```
$ git pull origin master          
$ git checkout --theirs -- .     # accept 'remote/master' changes
```